# Выводить каждый день дату на сайте на php

Tags: php, дата

Выводить каждый день дату на сайте на php и красиво ее стилизовать с сss

Answer (score 2):

Вообще документацию читать ни кто ни хочет?

```
<span class="date"><?=date("d.m.Y H:i:s)?></span>
```

И стили

```
.date {
    color: black;
}
```

[php date()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php)

Comment: Стилизовал действительно красиво) лукас

Comment: @Manitikyl старался как мог=)))) Лукас и тебе!=)